# Definition of “morphism of schemes that induces a bijection between irreducible components ”

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, definitions

$\def\sO{\mathcal{O}}\def\sF{\mathcal{F}}$On the Stacks Project there are several instances where the seemingly undefined notion of a “morphism of schemes that induces a bijection between irreducible components” is invoked, see [037A](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/037A), [037O](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/037O), [01RO](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01RO), [035L](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035L), [035Q](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035Q); an [internal search](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/search?query=bijection+irreducible+components&page=1&perpage=oo&radius=all) throws even more instances.

My question is:

> What is the definition of this concept?

I guess J. de Jong is the person that can ultimately answer this question, but I am asking here since maybe the notion is explicitly defined in other sources (knowing which would help too).

Until today, I thought the definition was:

> **Definition 1.** We say that a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ of topological spaces
> *induces a bijection between irreducible components*
> if for all irreducible components $Z\subset X$, it holds that
> $\overline{f(Z)}$ is an irreducible component and the map
> $Z\mapsto \overline{f(Z)}$ is a bijection between sets of irreducible components.

This notion is local on the target, stable under composition and it satisfies that if $g\circ f$ and $f$ have the property, then so does $g$.

The situation for schemes is the expected one:

> **Lemma 2.** Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map between sober topological spaces.
> Then $f$ induces a bijection between irreducible components (in the sense of Definition 1)
> if and only if
> for every generic point $\xi\in X$ of an irreducible component of $X$, $f(\xi)$ is a generic point of an irreducible component of $Y$ and
> $\xi\mapsto f(\xi)$ is a bijection between sets of generic points of
> irreducible components.

(The proof is because $f(x)=y$ iff $\overline{f\left(\overline{\{x\}}\right)}=\overline{\{y\}}$, for $X$, $Y$ are sober.) I said “until today” because so far I worked on my mind with this definition when reading SP. However, I just noticed that [01RO](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01RO) references:

> **EGA I, (2.2.9)** Soient $(X,\sO_X)$, $(Y,\sO_Y)$ deux préschémas; on suppose que $X$ et $Y$ ont un même nombre *fini* de composantes irréductibles $X_i$ (resp. $Y_i$) ($1\leq i\leq n$); soit $\xi_i$ (resp., $\eta_i$) le point générique de $X_i$ (resp. $Y_i$). On dit qu'un morphisme
> $$
> f=(\psi,\theta):(X,\sO_X)\to(Y,\sO_Y)
> $$
> est *birationnel* si, pour tout $i$, $\psi^{-1}(\eta_i)=\{\xi_i\}$ et $\theta_{\xi_i}^\sharp:\sO_{\eta_i}\to\sO_{\xi_i}$ est un *isomorphisme*.

From this, one could argue that what SP calls “inducing a bijection on irreducible components” means “one has Definition 1 AND $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is a singleton for every generic point $\eta\in Y$ of an irreducible component.” This is a strictly stronger condition (consider a morphism $X\to \operatorname{Spec}k$ with $X$ irreducible and with more than one point).

What is the correct definition then? Maybe my definition and EGA's implicit one are equivalent in the case from Grothendieck's text quoted above? Explicitly:

> **Problem.** Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes with finitely many irreducible components such that for every generic point $\xi\in X$ of an irreducible component, $\sO_{Y,f(\xi)}\to\sO_{X,\xi}$ is an iso. Then $f:X\to Y$ satisfies Definition 1 above implies that $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is a singleton for every generic point $\eta\in Y$ of an irreducible component.

This is what I thought for a proof: Let $x\in f^{-1}(\eta)$. Let $\xi\in X$ be the generic point of an irreducible component passing through $x$; in particular, $\xi\rightsquigarrow x$. Hence, $f(\xi)\rightsquigarrow f(x)=\eta$. By minimality, $f(\xi)=\eta$. Thus, we have a commutative diagram

[image]

(the map $\sO_{X,x}\to\sO_{X,\xi}$ is defined in the following way: if $\sF$ is a sheaf over a topological space $A$ and $a,b\in A$ are s.t. $a\rightsquigarrow b$, then there is a natural map $\sF_b\to\sF_a$.)

Since the top map is an iso (by hypothesis), then the left and right maps are injective and onto, respectively. But here's when I get stuck; I don't see how to go any further.

Comment: I think what SP means is simply that the induced map between sets of irreducible components is bijective, nothing more. This condition + generic points are sent to generic points + isos on local rings (i.e., 01RO) is equivalent to birational in the sense of EGA.

Comment: Your definition of "induces a bijection on irreducible components" seems correct. This is not in contradiction with Tag 01RO, nor with the EGA reference: both of these define the notion of birational morphism. Birational morphisms induce bijections on irreducible components, but the converse is not true.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Two questions: (1) isn't “generic points are sent to generic points” redundant in what you said? (by Lemma 2 above) (2) How would the proof of the equivalence between the two definitions of birationality would go? I just edited the post to make question (2) completely explicit (the 'problem' at the end).

Comment: @ThibaultPoiret same question (2) I made to Marc Hoyois in the comment above: How does one prove the equivalence between the two definitions of birationality? (see 'problem' at the end of my post.)

Comment: My understanding of "bijection on irreducible components" is weaker than yours; for example, I would say that any map between irreducible schemes has this property, even though it need not preserve generic points (but I agree that your Definition 1 is a more reasonable notion). Regarding the "Problem", the point $\xi$ is closed in its fiber (since $\kappa(\xi)=\kappa(\eta)$), so it doesn't have any specializations.

Comment: @MarcHoyois I'm sorry if this might be elementary or something, but why does $\kappa(\xi)=\kappa(\eta)$ imply that $\xi$ is closed in $f^{-1}(\eta)$? I've been thinking about it for a while now and I don't see why :/

Comment: Well, rational points are closed. I guess this boils down to the fact that a map of $k$-algebras $A\to k$ is automatically surjective, so its kernel, which is the underlying point in $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, is a maximal ideal.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Right, thank you very much ^^